# Custom Validation - Dependent Drop Down Lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I've two columns in a sheet that are interdependent and I want to use validation, drop-down lists, on both as follows:

```
Column A (TYPE) | Column B (Sub-TYPE)
------------------------------------------|
TypeA, TypeB    | If TypeA SubTypeA1,     |
... TypeN       | SubTypeA2 ... SubTypeAN |
------------------------------------------|
```

Creating the column A drop down is trivial. How do I create the Column B drop down, that in turn depends on what was chosen in Column A?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT function in Excel.

First create a named list consisting of values TypeA, TypeB, ... Let's call it "type"

[image]

Then create named lists for each group of subtypes. You can hide these lists later if you want.

[image]

Now to make them dependent, first select the cell in which you want the user to select the type and create a drop down list for types. To do this, select **Data Validation** from Data Menu/Ribbon. Under Allow select List, in Source textbox type "=" following the name of the list. i.e "=type" in our case

[image]

Finally use the indirect function to create dependent lists. Select Data Validation from Data Menu/Ribbon. Under Allow select List, in Source textbox type "=INDIRECT(E2)". Change the cell value "E2" to your cell destination where the first selection is done. Click YES if any information pop-up appears.

[image]

And here is the final result:

[image]